# Programacion en C++ basada en interrupciones para comunicacion de dos DTE (en serie)

Tags: c++, puertos

Mi duda especifica es:

En el código que tengo hay una linea que es:

```
 outportb(Puerto+3,0x80);/*Pone DLAB en 1*/
```

Por lo que leí este DLAB es un bit que se encuentra en el LCR(Line control Register)
osea puerto+3, accede al registro LCR, y con 0x80(que en decimal es 128) activa el DLAB...

Alguien me podría decir como es que con ese 0x80 activa el Dlab, Osea... porque es ese valor en especial? el 0x80?

Lei que estan algunos valores de Divisor Latch Low Byte(no se si tiene que ver) y uno que pone a una velocidad de 300Bps el valor es de 80h

voy a estar esperando de su respuesta chicos

Comment: ¿Programación en [tag:c] o en [tag:c++]? O la etiqueta o el título están mal.

Comment: Ahí lo corregí, igual mucho no creo que tenga que ver con mi duda... es en c++

Comment: `outportb` no pertenece a ninguna librería (que yo conozca) de [tag:c++] ¿con qué estás trabajando?

Comment: Si, y pertenece a la librería conio.h

Se llama como 
#include <conio.h>

Comment: `conio.h` es una cabecera de [tag:c] (no de [tag:c++]). `outportb` escribe el byte del segundo parámetro en el puerto del primer parámetro, el significado del `0x80` variará según lo que tengas conectado a dicho puerto.

Comment: Este código es uno que nos han dado en la facultad y tenemos que explicarlo así tal cual esta.. voy a subirlo para que todos lo vean, igual en todos lados leí que es el mismo(para realizar una comunicación entre un DTE y un DTE)

Comment: Claro tal cual, querría saber eso, y no tengo ninguna tabla que me diga. ¿Y como es eso que decís que varia de acuerdo a lo que tengas conectado?

Comment: Bueno, gracias, tenia la idea en el aire y necesitaba de alguien que sepa que me la afirme.

Comment: Claro claro tal cual, es muy extenso, pasa que esto es algo para la facu(manejamos conectores db-9)

Comment: Tal cual :D @Trauma

Comment: @Trauma ¿por qué no agrupas todos tus comentarios en una respuesta para que se de por buena? así evitamos empeorar las estadísticas de la etiqueta [tag:c]

Comment: @Trauma no hay que ser siempre tan estricto. Yo creo que la pregunta deja claro que es un tema muy concreto y tu respuesta terminará por reforzar la idea de que es algo "viejuno" y solo aplicable a esta pregunta